# Diablo-3 will not patch help please

Tags: diablo-iii

My diablo will not patch it says my game is up to date but when i launch the game it says that i need to patch it it will close the game and patch automaticly and as soon as patch is completed I will be able to play again, however when it closes and opens up the patch it says another instance of diablo is running and closes automatically. What should i do?

Comment: Did you try running it as administrator?

Comment: It is a temporary problem linked to server maintenance now in progress due to patch 1.02. It will be fixed by Blizzard on their side soon.

Comment: it is done i tried launching same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might just be that [the Americas server is down](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/status).

Comment: I susspect ill still have this problem even after maintance because It happens on a majority of the games I play and in the end i end up having to uninstall it so that all the patches get applied at once, if it happens even after the server what do you recomend i try?

Comment: One of my friends are actually having that same trouble right now --- as best as I know, it's never happened to him before, and it's definitely never happened to me (at least the schizophrenic patch issue). Are you sure it's the same error that you've been experiencing in the past?

Comment: I can't see how this is a useful question for this site; its a technical support issue and better addressed on official forums. Why not wait till Blizzard officially announces the downtime is over and then ask here if you still have problems?

Comment: its a question that can be answered alok and tech support never responds so why are you mad?

Comment: ^ Giving Alok the benefit of the doubt, he has a point though. Double-checking the site FAQs, however, the question seems to stand sufficiently.